# Adsense doesn't appears in new browser tab

Tags: wordpress, safari, adsense

I have a web site which works under WordPress. And i've added Google Adsense to it's sidebar. The problem is when i open new tab and go to this site the Adsense block doesn't appear. But it appears if i just refresh page or open new page by clicking on any link.

I am trying to fix this problem about 2 past weeks but i have no idea :(. It works perfectly in all browsers, but not in Safari. This problem is gained by the fact that most of site's visitors use Safari.

The site address is storios.ru. It is in Russian. Please help me to find a problem :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you in incorporating Google ads on your website
http://www.therdnotes.com/2014/01/google-publisher-plugin-wordpress.html